# SPD Workflow not looping on item changed

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a reminder workflow on a task list. It simply checks if the task has been completed and then sends a reminder email if it hasn't. It then pauses for a period of time and then updates a field in the task item. As I have set 'Start workflow automatically when an item is changed' the workflow should then start again.

The problem is the workflow only runs once. I am not using a system account to test this and the item actually shows that it has been updated by a user.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

From Sharepoint 2007 SP2 onward, a workflow cannot retrigger itself by updating the item its running on. To do this, you will have to create a second list and a second workflow. Have your existing workflow create or update an item on that list and set the workflow on that list to update the item in your original list. This will get around the problem.

Note, that the pause you've put in will remain essential if you want this loop to run perpetually. If you don't have a pause, the loop will stop after 5 iterations.